# Kendo-UI SPA Race Condition

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm implementing [Kendo-UI's SPA](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/spa/overview) classes to implement a CRUD screen. Without going into much detail, I have an observable that has properties that represent the various "interfaces", e.g. Search, Create, Update. Removing all of the fluff, it looks something like this:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    search: kendo.observable({
        filterPayload: kendo.observable({}),
        init: function() {
            // setup kendo-ui controls
        },
        show: function() {
            // grid's dataSource read
        }
    }),
    add: kendo.observable({
        insertPayload: kendo.observable({}),
        init: function() {
            // setup kendo-ui controls
        },
        show: function() {
            // reset the form by calling:
            // viewModel.add.insertPayload.set("[property name]", null);
        }
    }),
    update: kendo.observable({
        entityId: null,
        updatePayload: kendo.observable({}),
        init: function() {
            // setup kendo-ui controls
        },
        show: function() {
            // Read from the database using viewModel.update.entityId
            // Set the default values of the form using the results returned
        }
    }),
});
```

Where I'm running into a race condition is in the `viewModel.update.show` What's happening is that I'm setting up a [kendoMultiSelect](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect) in the `init` the populates data from the server but also setting the values of `viewModel.update.updatePayload` by hitting the server in the `show`. This is causing a race condition (sometimes) when the user first visits the update interface where the data returned from the database for the default values is quicker than the multiSelect being setup causing the multiSelect to look like has no values selected.

Is there any design pattern I can implement to prevent this race condition or am I forced to potentially handle the logic in the "show" twice?

Comment: What I do in similar-ish scenarios is `const multiSelectData: any[] = await getMultiSelectData()`, and then initialize the multi-select with a static array. Alternatively, `await multiSelect.dataSource.read()`, or bind some event handler with [one](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/observable/methods/one) instead of `bind`.